# Unable to add files to source control using VS 2015 and GIT

Tags: git, visual-studio, github

One of my clients added me to their private GITHUB repo. It is a Visual Studio 2010 solution written in C#.

I have GIT installed on my dev PC. My procedure was to load up VS 2015, go to Team Explorer -> Local Git Repositories, then Clone. I entered the GITHUB URL for this client's repo and was asked for my GITHUB username/password.

Everything seemed to work. I see no errors. The progress bar displayed as expected and the local repo was created. Now I can see the solution and all of its projects. I am able to build the solution and even run/debug it.

I see padlocks to the left of files. If I edit one of these files I will see a red check mark indicating the file is checked out.

The problem I am experiencing is that I can't add a file to the solution and include it in source control. Normally I can drag/drop or copy/paste files and they are added to source control. I have even tried adding item by right clicking. No matter what I do, the file is added but there is no icon to the left of it to indicate its source control status - of course, I am expecting a `+` sign. Of course, the added file is also not showing up under Changes.

Another symptom is if I rename an existing file. At first it has a padlock. When I rename the file it will not have a status icon to it at all.

I've read a ton of posts from people with a similar problem, but none of those solutions are effecting mine. I'm not seeing any errors, so I don't know what would be relevant to include in this post. :S

**EDIT**

I am obviously not a GIT guru... but I do understand that the padlock is telling me `read only` (I think). I don't know why and haven't been able to find a clue. Thought someone might point me in a good direction. When I add a file I do see the `+` sign very momentarily, but then it disappears and no errors are shown in output window.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're getting downvoted and voted to close - IDEs and source control tooling are obviously on topic.  Indeed you should see these files in Team Explorer's Changes page.  What kind of projects are in your solution?  Do you have any Web Site projects?

Comment: think there's a troll following me around. I'll report it. I discovered I'm able to add and delete items (files) using File Explorer context menu for GIT Extensions. Though this works, the change isn't reflected in Visual Studio until I restart it. It might be a local permissions issue in Visual Studio. None of my other local repositories exhibit this problem. The solution is a desktop application with about a dozen custom DLL projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use commint -> Untracked Files(bottom) -> Right click - Add files

Comment: I had the same problem, and it's worked for me. First you have to change anything in one of the files under source control. Then, use COMMIT, expand UNTRACKED FILES, and all the files that aren't under source controll will be showed.

Comment: In some cases, you have to expand INCLUDED CHANGES to ensure that all files to be included under source control are listed. It not, expand EXCLUDED CHANGES and include them.

Comment: @Marcelo, where is the UNTRACKED FILES option in Visual Studio?

Comment: @zameb, I can't remember very well, but it was displayed in "CHANGES" tab, on Team Explorer, but as I see now, this option is not there. Maybe because I updated  the "VS 2015", or maybe because I have no "untrackable files" in my project. In fact, when one file seems like "untrackable", I just exclude it from the project and then, I include it again.

Comment: I consider this a not so nice way to do source control, why do I have to change something elsewhere to be to add a new file to source control!

Answer (score 1):

Try copying and pasting the file manually into the solution folder, then use "Add an existing item" to add it to the solution. I was having the same exact problem and this fixed it for me, the GitHub plugin found the new file when I went into Team Explorer => Changes just as any other.